# Resigning from a 1 year internship

Tags: internship, resignation

My parents have recently split and I'm moving an extra 40 minutes away from my job's workplace. I have been working on a business as a side-job whilst working my main job. The business has now started to take in reasonable money and I would like to leave my internship and work on my business full-time.

The thing is my internship clearly stated a "1 year appointment".. there was no official contract that I signed saying I couldn't leave but it just doesn't feel right. I've been here for 5 months now, how much damage will it do if I leave now?

I'm 17 years of age and am earning quite a bit above the average salary for my age so it's not an easy decision...

I have a meeting in 4 hours with my boss in which I'm going to start to hint a possible resignation... any ideas how I should go about this?

Comment: 40 minutes away is really not much! You shouldn't resign only because a bit more of trafficing. In big cities, it's normal to commute 1,5 hour or even more (in one side).

Comment: @Lukasz The extra travel time isn't really the main point of my argument (I can't drive yet, it would actually be up to 1.5 hours on public transport), the fact is more that I want to leave the job to focus fully on my business. I really like Phil's answer, he explains that business sometimes costs hard decisions, and I completely agree with him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I concur with Ajaxkevi here, but I would add this: In childhood, much of life is about obligations and duties and doing what you *should* do. In adulthood, however, you will see that plans and circumstances change, and that expectations of behaviour are more about approach (i.e. being clear and curteous to your boss) and less about about actions.

You have not signed a binding contract, nor would one likely be even legal in most countries. You can do your best to keep the relationship with the company positive, and it will probably stay that way. It is worth keeping in mind that if you have been a great employee they won't want to sour the relationship either as you might go back and work there one day. They have no legal or even social right to demand you see out your term, since the circumstances that are causing the change are largely out of your control.

As a side note, congratulations on creating a business at any age let alone so young. Success in business often requires you to make hard decisions about honouring vague agreements or not, or about honouring one arrangement over another. As long as you treat people fairly and openly, you will have a clear conscience when you need to give people unfortunate news.

Comment: Thanks for your advice dude. Well here goes nothing... time to walk to my manager's office

Answer (score 6):

Explain your current situation and tell him how you feel about it. Stay polite, gratefull and professional. **If you really want to leave, don't burn any bridges!**

The not feeling right part, you are going to get a lot in your future career.

I resigned from a company recently, which I had tons of fun at and made tons of friends at. Leaving felt like leaving my friends and the company behind and sure didn't feel right.

But now I have a job that fits me better, I feel better and my previous company is running just fine.

Just try not to burn any bridges, **always stay professional**! Be polite, ask for referrals within the company if you feel like you've earned it and thank your boss for the great oppurtunity given.